# AngularJS + Ionic: Checking if new Entry in Database, if yes: Push notification

Tags: mysql, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working on an application with ionic and angularjs. I would like, that the app checks automatically in the background, if new database entries are available. If yes, it should send a notification. My question: How can I check in the background continiously, if there is an database update? 
And Question #2: If there is no entry in the database, it should throw you out of the actual page.

Background: I am working on an live-survey app for events, with which you can interact with the show on the stage. If a question is activated for the people, you should get a notification.

Answer (score 0):

1 - for continuously checks you should use `cron job` from your server side and based on it you can send your notifications

2- if there is no entries you can send push notification with any flag in its payload and check on it in the mobile app then execute the desired behavior.